# One-time URL to change a user's field value

Tags: users, uri

How can I create a one-time URL (sent through email messages) users can use to change the value of a custom field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunatelly, there is a way.

You can copy function "user_pass_reset_url" and form "user_pass_reset" and customize it for your needs. With first you create custom link and with the second you can get "one-time-link" logic.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Drupal requires that users reset their passwords when using the one time login link.

The easiest way to avoid that would be to use a module like [URL Login](https://drupal.org/project/urllogin), which generates login links for each of your users. There are a couple of modules which cater for similar use cases so you'll need to find out which one works best for you.

You can then use [LogginToboggan](https://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) to redirect your users to your custom page where they can edit the custom field. You may need to create a custom User Role depending on the need for access control.